# bot.get_all_channels() gets ignored discord.py

Tags: discord.py

When obtaining all channels to send a message to all, the bot ignores the command. Here's my code.

```py
async def lockdown(ctx):
  allchannels = bot.get_all_channels()
  overwrite = channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
  locked = overwrite.send_messages = False
  await locked.send(allchannels, 'This server has been locked down.')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ignores the command"? What exactly happens? Also - where did you define `channel`?

Comment: By ignores the command, I mean it just doesn't send a message. The error says, "TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator." Also, I didn't define channel.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing allchannel, you'll see where you did an error.
You can't use `bot.get_all_channels()` in this way that's all